# Which is Key_F13

Tags: qt, keyboard, qt5

I am developing a program where we need to implement **Key F13** but I can't find F13 in keyboard.
Can someone please tell me which code belongs to **Key F13** in normal keyboard.

I can use Key F11 and Key F12 but I am not sure what is the F13 key code. The following link mentions "Key_13": https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.Key.html

Comment: AFAIK, in order to access key F13 you should press `SHIFT` key in combination with `F1` key, i.e. `Shift+F1`.

Comment: You can find key codes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN
F13 code is 0x7C = 124

Comment: The link in your question is very old. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) is a more up to date link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that somewhere out in the world, there exists a keyboard with the F13-F24 keys, but I haven't seen any so far. So if you don't have one of those weird keyboards, you can access these keys by pressing shift: Shift+F1 becomes F13, Shift+F2 becomes F14, etc...

Comment: How would you emulate Shift+F13 then?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot keyboard which have an additonal F-Key row F13-F24 (especially older ones - look for old IBM boards) and also some of the newer custom keyboard feature F13 keys like the recently introduced NovelKeys NK87. In general it is a standard keycode and if you have no physical key assigned to it, you can remap another physical key to F13 by software or firmware (just look up QMK firmware).

Answer (score 0):

try from F1 to F12  (in VIM after typing i_ctrl-v):

```
F1 + shift  -> F13
F12 + shift -> F24
F12 + ctrl  -> F36
F12 + alt   -> F60
```